# Autoloader not working import, discover & registerPrefix

Tags: autoload

I have an extension that is using autoloader to import helpers.

Everything works well in localhost development environment but in the live server the classes are not loaded. I get the error "*Fatal error: Class 'MYExtensionText' not found*"

1) In `components/com_myextension/myextension.php` I have this code:

```
JLoader::import('MYExtension', __DIR__ . '/helpers');
```

2) In `components/com_myextension/helpers/myextension.php` I have this code:

```
JLoader::discover('MYExtension', __DIR__);
JLoader::registerPrefix('MYExtension', __DIR__);
```

3) So, I expect that this classes are autoloaded in `components/com_myextension/helpers/`

```
myextension.php / MYExtension 
text.php / MYExtensionText
model/list.php / MYExtensionModelList
```

This WORKS FINE in localhost (mamp with php 5.5) but does not work in the server, using CentOS 5 with php 5.4.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you try adding `var_dump(__DIR__);` to `components/com_myextension/myextension.php` on both your localhost **and** live host. Would like to know if the results are the same

Comment: Hello Lodder I did it, the output is the absolute path to the file folder in both environments

Comment: Hmm, If the paths are exactly the same then I'm not sure what the issue could be. Could you possibly try replacing `__DIR__` with `JPATH_ROOT . '/components/com_myextension/helpers/'`

Comment: Tried JPATH_COMPONENT . '/helpers' and neither works. No errors other than "Fatal error: Class 'MYExtensionText' not found"

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution:

```
JLoader::import('myextension', JPATH_COMPONENT . '/helpers');
```

Please note the lower case!